# How to use D structures from C code?

Tags: c, d

Could anyone explain me how to use D structures from C code? If I am trying to use it I receive such an error:

```
error: storage size of 'myStruct' isn't known
   struct str_struct myStruct;
```

This is a structure:

```
extern(C) {
    struct str_struct {
        string str;
      };
}
```

I use it in C like this : `struct str_struct myStruct;`

Comment: C does not have a type called `string`.

Comment: Year. I know it. But D has. But it still doesn't work even if I change it to int.

Comment: You have to duplicate the struct definition with all members in both languages (unless you want to refer to it only by pointer). C can't see a field list written in D.

Comment: cool, I just posted it as an answer too so it is easier to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to duplicate the struct definition with all members in both languages (unless you want to refer to it only by pointer). C can't see a field list written in D.

D:

```
struct Foo {
    int length;
    int* data;
}
```

C:

```
typedef struct Foo {
    int length;
    int* data;
};
```

The tricky thing is to get long right. `long` in D is always 64 bits, so in C, that would be `long long`. Most other basic types translate pretty easily though: `short`=>`short`, int to int, char to char, pointers work the same way, etc.

Comment: Could you add an example?

Comment: yeah, it is usually pretty simple though: pretty close to copy/paste for basic types. The biggest difference is often D's ushort => C's unsigned short. the tricky part is handling longs, since they don't really match up.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunatelly I have no 15 reputation points to vote your comment up.